# What is this triangle shape thing that holds the bottom of shade to the door

Tags: mounting, brackets, blinds

I am wondering what is this triangle shape plastic thing that holds the bottom of the shade to the door?

I need to buy multiple of them but I don't know the name.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They are called mini-blind hold down brackets and can be purchased on E'bay, Amazon, and at Walmart, Lowes, Home Depot etc.

Answer (score 1):

That right there appears to be an RV hold down bracket.

Answer (score 0):

It is a blinds bracket and you can find them here https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-m&q=blind+hold+down+bracket&oq=blind+hold+&aqs=heirloom-srp.0.0l5